# Excel: divide a number by the number of times a ";" appears in a cell that contains ";" and a "word" in a range

Tags: excel, select, count, excel-formula

I would like to select cells in a range that contains ";" and either of two words "SUN" or "SUNNY" and then I would like to divide a number by the number of times ";" appears in those cells, e.g.. if there are 4 cells containing ";" and either "SUN" or "SUNNY" and each one of those cells contains ";" 2 times, then it should divide the number by 8.
Is this possible in excel? perhaps using two or more separated formulas? or cells?

Here is what I have made so far:

```
COUNTIFS(DB3:DB50,DC26,DB3:DB50,$D$1)
```

to count if "SUN" or "SUNNY" appear

```
=(LEN(I3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(I3,";",""))
```

to "count" the number of times ";" appears, but, by using this formula I have to search within an specific cell "I3", I would to search within cells that contain ";" and either of two words "SUN" or "SUNNY"

I need this formula above to do the same, but in a range of cells (all rows of column A) not only within an specific cell (A1 or A2, etc.) Is this possible?

I really need to avoid repeating the formula in each row of column B because every column will be looking for a different couple of words (eg. SUN SUNNY, CLOUD, CLOUDY, RAIN, RAINY).

For example:

[image]

Then I would just sum column C, is there a way to achieve this??

Comment: ?? If **SUNNY** appears in a cell then **SUN** must also be in the cell??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just putting @Gary's Student's formula into an array formula so it repeats over the 6 cells:-)

```
=SUM(ISNUMBER(FIND("SUN",$A$1:$A$6))*(LEN($A$1:$A$6)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$1:$A$6,";",""))))
```

and then repeat for  wind etc.

It has to be entered starting at B1 with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

I think you can even do it in one go if you aren't bothered about having the separate totals:-

```
=SUM(ISNUMBER(FIND({"SUN","CLOUD","ETC"},$A$1:$A$6))*(LEN($A$1:$A$6)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$1:$A$6,";",""))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=--OR(ISNUMBER(FIND("SUNNY",A1)),ISNUMBER(FIND("SUN",A1)))*(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,";","")))
```

and copy down.

Then the **divisor** will be sum sum of column **B**:

[image]

You can adapt this for your choice of columns.

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks, but you are repeating the formula in B1 in every cell of columm B, I can't do this, cuz every columm will be looking for a different par of words (eg. SUN SUNNY, CLOUD, CLOUDY, RAIN, RAINNY) I need the formula to do the same, but in a range of cell(all A columm) not only an specific cel (A1, A2, etc) Is this possible???

Comment: @Gary I came up with more or less the same formula but you got there first - I gave +1 I think deservedly before the extra info was posted.

Comment: so do I in the first question post, please any ideas?

Comment: @litu16 I can do what you want with a **User Defined Function** - is this approach O.K. with you???

Comment: if data could be calculated automatically in several columms, its ok